# How to add support of IPv6 using pjsip with Domain in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, pjsip

I make the VOIP app. Now added ipv6 in ios code but it's working with IP only.insted of IP we used domain then give us an error.
Error:- "503(Bad gateway)."

Used below code for additional support of ipv6.

```
pj_status_t status;
pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg;
const char *uname;
const char *authname;
const char *contactname;
const char *passwd;
const char *server;
//const char *proxy;

NSLog(@"isIPv6 = %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isIPv6"]);

uname  = authname = contactname = [SharedAppDelegate.username UTF8String];//[@"4069567731" UTF8String];//
passwd = [SharedAppDelegate.password UTF8String];//[@"4069567731" UTF8String];//
server = (char*)[SharedAppDelegate.baseurl UTF8String];//[@"voiceforfriends.info" UTF8String];//

NSLog(@"Name is--->%s",uname);
NSLog(@"password is-->%s",passwd);
NSLog(@"server is--->%s",server);

NSLog(@"IPv6 flag = %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isIPv6"]);

if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isIPv6"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    server = [@"[2607:feb8::4:ce]:7777" UTF8String]; 
    
}
contactname = nil;

//pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);
printf("1");
pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);
```

So now I want to use Domain instead of Ip for ipv6.

So anyone has solution then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which server you are using? FreeSWITCH or Kamailio

Comment: @ShahbazAbbasi we are using freeswitch

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this issue on Server side as well.

There are two changes you need to made on server side.

1. Configuration level
2. OS level

**1. Configuration level**
You need to open **vars.xml** file and paste following code inside that file.

> <X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="set" data="domain=yourdomain.com”/>

**2. OS level**
You need to go to this path /etc/hosts/ and add this line.

> 127.0.0.1 localhost yourdomain.com

Note : Don't forget to replace my sample domain address with your original domain address.

Comment: Shahbaz,
i want it in objective c for ios.

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani you can't do this on client side. Other solution is you can use third party/company to create entry for DNS by providing him domain name and your ip address. They will slightly charge you for this.